# Rails 4: Using PostgreSQL function in order causes error in query due to the includes table not being joined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I found an odd problem with Rails 4 Active Record queries where the includes table is not joined if I use a PostgreSQL function in the order.  This same query works fine if I remove the PostgreSQL function.

This works fine...

```
Widget.includes(:sprocket).order("sprockets.name").all
```

This fails because the includes relationship is not joined...

```
Widget.includes(:sprocket).order("lower(sprockets.name)").all
```

Notice the only thing different is the lower(sprockets.name).

I know I can add .references like this...

```
Widget.includes(:sprocket).references(:sprockets).order("lower(sprockets.name)").all
```

That will work, but then what is the purpose of the includes?

I've found that replacing includes with eager_load works also, but again, what is the purpose of includes then?

```
Widget.eager_load(:sprocket).order("lower(sprockets.name)").all
```

In Rails 3, just using includes works fine.  I guess I have a lot of code to change, but just hoping there is an easier fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need to get the user name of first five post. You quickly write the query below and go enjoy your weekend.

```
posts = Post.limit(5)

posts.each do |post|
  puts post.user.name
end
```

Good. But let's look at the queries

```
Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE  `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

`1 query` to fetch all `posts` and `1 query` to fetch `users` for each post results in a total of `6 queries`. Check out the solution below which does the same thing, just in `2 queries`:

```
posts = Post.includes(:user).limit(5)

posts.each do |post|
  puts post.user.name
end

#####

Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2)
```

There’s one little difference. Add `includes(:posts)` to your query, and problem solved. Quick, nice, and easy.

But don’t just add `includes` in your query without understanding it properly. Using `includes` with `joins` might result in cross-joins depending on the situation, and you don’t need that in most cases.

**If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to explicitly reference them**. For example:

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')
```

Will throw an error, but this will work:

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)
```

Note that `includes` works with `association names` while `references` needs `the actual table name`.

Comment: This is a great write-up Phong Phan.  Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear that